# Any idea if/when temperature sensors will be accessible via Nest Thermostat API?

Tags: api, nest, sensors, google-home, temperature

I know they are not accessible now. Nest can clearly see this data. I have 2 additional sensors (thermostat 1st floor, 1 sensor basement, 1 sensor 2nd floor) and want to log/measure and potentially even control based of those and the Nest app is quite poor with this. (ie you can only change the sensor you are using 4x in a day, at specific times).
In real-life usage, where I am on different stories at different times of day (which don't correspond with the canned choices) it would be nice to be able to read these and potentially control. In some cases I want to just reduce the difference in temperature between the areas, others I might want to make sure my kids are comfortable during naps but without access to the sensor data it's quite useless...

It is clear that the sensors aren't currently supported by the API but this is where it redirects me to ask questions! Any idea?

EDIT: ok so it looks like technically you can read the sensor data but only when the sensor is set as the current sensor. Listed this and other findings so far here: https://ssprod.me/blog/2022/11/14/a-closer-look-at-the-nest-thermostat/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -2):

Currently, there is no support for temperature sensors via Nest Thermostat API. Our teams are working continuously on incorporating new capabilities. What’s currently available is only reading the temperature from thermostats. You can also go through the following [codelab](https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/codelabs/web-app) to get more ideas in this regard.

Comment: How do we request support for this. There is an entire community of smart vent users that want API access for the temperature sensors.